# What does this regex validate? What are examples of what will match and not match?

Tags: regex, url-validation

This is the URL validator scraped from the validator npm module. I'm new to regex, does anyone mind helping me decode this? And perhaps mentioning url's the will match vs not match?

```
(/^(?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$/i)
```

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: You need to see it first. Get this software http://regexformat.com

Answer (score 1):

This is a URL validator designed to capture as many of the documented url (and IP address) standards as possible.

I'd recommend adding it to [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) to learn about it and test various matches.

Here's an example for you to play around with -- simply change the url in the test string to see the result. http://regex101.com/r/jQ1lZ5

Some examples it will match:

- www.google.com
- http://www.google.com
- 12.20.140.25
- localhost

Some that it will not match:

- wwww..google.com
- http:://www.google.com
- 12.20.140.256 (not a valid IP address!)
- local_host

Answer (score 0):

You certainly have to read about regexp. Anyway, here are some tips (non exhaustive):

```
^ : out of a class it matches the beginning of a string
^ : in a class it makes your class a negation class
$ : matches the end of a string
() : creates group which could be reusable, quantifiable, etc.
? : tells the last character or group can be present once or not present
+ : tells the last character or group is present at least once
* : tells the last character or group can be present once or more or not present
\ : escape the following char. Usefull is you have to match a character which is also a metacharacter 
| : is for alternative 
{x, y} : allow you to quantify more precisely than *, ? or +
[] : allow you to create class. [abc] is equivalent to a|b|c
? : after a + or * make it non greedy. By default quantifier are greedy (match the langest string possible)
```

Comment: Yes, I do need to read-up on regexp :) 
Thank you so much for the tips -- this was really helpful in understanding the url validator!

Answer (score -1):

In computing, a regular expression (abbreviated regex or regexp) is a sequence of characters that forms a search pattern, mainly for use in pattern matching with strings, or string matching, i.e. "find and replace"-like operations. The concept arose in the 1950s, when the American mathematician Stephen Kleene formalized the description of a regular language, and came into common use with the Unix text processing utilities ed, an editor, and grep (global regular expression print), a filter.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a primer on regular expressions, he asked for an explanation of the regex he posted.  And in any case, copying the first paragraph from a Wikipedia page does not constitute an answer.

Comment: As a side, Wikipedia is highly overrated.